# Using the ".value" property of a textbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
document.getElementById("t3").value = document.getElementById("t1").value + 
                                      document.getElementById("t2");
```

Through above code I could not get the result of addition of two numbers.

Comment: Need more info; what kind of element is #t3?

Comment: Form control values are strings, so `+` is concatenating the values as strings, not performing addition of numbers.

Comment: Can you give us the whole html and javascript snippets? What event are you binding to for this to fire?

Comment: Are the numbers integers or might you need to accept decimals?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add those to values, you have to convert them to integer at first. `.value` always holds a string.

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value, 10) + parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value, 10);
```

Comment: If you must use `parseInt`, you need to use the radix argument as well.

Comment: @lonesomeday good point although I believe it defaults to base 10 in  ECMAScript 5

Comment: @Moob And when the string is `012`? ECMAScript 5 compliant browsers will use base 10, but others may not. And what about `0x12`? How would you like the browser to treat that? (All these questions are solved by using the unary plus operator...)

Comment: this solution is an accurate one, but lonesomeday's solution is really elegant. Both answers voted up, for each reason. However, when working on a team with a range of experience, I believe this is a better solution for everyone being able to immediately read and understand.

Comment: @lonesomeday I totally agree. Unary plus operator is the way to go. I'm just pointing out to those using parseInt that it defaults to base 10 in ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually adding two numbers together. You are attempting to add `document.getElementById("t1").value` (which is a string containing with numbers in it) to `document.getElementById("t2")`, which is a DOM element.

You probably get a result like this:

```
43[object HTMLInputElement]
```

You need to (a) get the `value` property of the second element and (b) add them together as numbers, rather than as strings.

```
document.getElementById("t3").value = (+document.getElementById("t1").value) + 
                                      (+document.getElementById("t2").value);
```

`(+document.getElementById("t1").value)` converts the value into a number. It is the [unary plus `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("t3").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value,10) + 
                                  parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value,10);
```

Comment: How is that different to the OP?

Comment: @RobG OP missed to get the value `document.getElementById("t2").value`

Comment: Yes, but it will still do concatenation, not addition.

Comment: As I mentioned on Florian's post, if you must use `parseInt`, you really should use the radix argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is cheeky, but on the off-chance the `t3` element that the OP is trying to update is a `div` or `span` rather than an `input` :)

```
var t1, t2, t3;

t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
t3 = document.getElementById("t3");

t3.innerHTML = parseInt(t1.value, 10) + parseInt(t2.value, 10);
```

Or

```
t3.innerHTML = +t1.value + +t2.value;
```